# nodes not working in launch file

Tags: ros, roslaunch, rosbag, static-transform-publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello guys,
I have the problem that some nodes are not working from launch file. Specifically the tf static_transform_publisher and also the rosbag record. I do not get any error but they are not working in the launch file. When i  run them in  terminal using rosrun they work perfectly!

any solution or suggestion for this problem?

one the launch files is:

```
<launch>
  <master auto="start"/>
  <param name="/use_sim_time" value="true"/>
 
  <node name="play" pkg="rosbag" type="play" args="-r 0.99 /home/mypack/vicon3_2014-12-26-17-33-16.bag"/>
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" 
         name="odom_to_world" args="4.53429770054 2.62724045772 0.568230440739 0.0554815495188 0.998340882582 -0.0146944327274 -0.00462098201913  world laser  100" />

  <node name="vicon2pos" pkg="mypack" type="vicon2pos" args="/Pioneer /Table1" output="screen"/>
  <node name="vicon2pos2" pkg="mypack" type="v2pos" args="/Pioneer /Table1" output="screen"/>
  <!-- Run the rivz -->
  <node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" args="-d /home/mypack/vicon.vcg" />

 
</launch>
```

The static_transform_publisher, vicon2pos and v2pos are not working properly in the launch file. Actually, the transform_publisher is not publishing anything and the other two nodes are not even subscribe to topics played in rosbag. Running command lines in terminals, all are working properly!!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200218/nodes-not-working-in-launch-file/) by [Anas Alhashimi](https://answers.ros.org/users/10201/anas-alhashimi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 179 on 2014-12-30

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2014-12-30**:
Can you post the launch file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to [this](http://ros-users.122217.n3.nabble.com/use-sim-time-td779886.html) post on ros-users, you have to start `rosbag` with the `--clock` argument for `use_sim_time` to work properly with `static_transform_publisher` (and probably other nodes as well):

> The output of roswtf reported the following:

> ```
> "ERROR /use_simtime is set but no publisher of /clock is present"
> ```

> Setting use_simtime to true and playing the bag with the --clock option resolved all issues.

You will probably see the same output if you start your launchfile and then run `roswtf`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-01-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Anas Alhashimi](https://answers.ros.org/users/10201/anas-alhashimi/) on 2015-01-08**:
Thanks That fixes every thing :)
I think this comment should be written with the rosbag play commandline details.